# org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain is not available in the jar of oozie-core-4.0.0-cdh5.1.0.jar

Tags: java, oozie, cloudera-cdh

Please see the code snippet below . it has method getLauncherClasses which is using PIG_MAIN_CLASS_NAME
however i am not finding any class in the jar with given package "org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain"

public class PigActionExecutor extends ScriptLanguageActionExecutor {

```
private static final String PIG_MAIN_CLASS_NAME = "org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain";
public PigActionExecutor() {
    super("pig");
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public List<Class> getLauncherClasses() {
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
    try {
        classes.add(Class.forName(PIG_MAIN_CLASS_NAME));
        classes.add(JSONParser.class);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Class not found", e);
    }
    return classes;
}
```

why PIG_MAIN_CLASS_NAME is missing in jar?

Answer (score 0):

This PigMain class is expected to be loaded from oozie share lib path . In my case oozie-sharelib-pig-4 was containing PigMain.